# Visual Studio 2019, C# codebase, Is it possible to change the name of a reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2019

I've got an odd concern here. I think I may need to change the name of a reference in my VS project, although I'm not sure this is even possible.

I have a VS project that was provided to me by an industrial camera manufacturer. In their project, which runs as expected, they have a reference named "ArenaNET". The actual name of that file is ArenaNETd_v140.dll yet somehow their project loads it in as "ArenaNET", as I said above.

In my project, which is attempting to run their exact same code, I've added a reference to the same file, 
ArenaNETd_v140.dll, and my project loads it in as "ArenaNETd_v140". My project, when I run it, complains:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'ArenaNETd_v140, Version=1.0.7347.17842, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.'

It's likely that I'm missing something here, maybe using the reference wrong, but it strikes me as odd that between my project and the project provided to me, the only difference appears to be in the name of the reference. So with that, I'd like to ask 2 questions:

1. Does the name of the reference in a C# Framework Project matter?
2. Can the name of the reference be changed, within Visual Studio? (2019 or earlier)

---

EDITS:

Looking more at the VS project provided to me, it looks like their project has a build dependancy on another project in their folder, named ArenaNET. This must be where that name is coming from. It appears the difference between my project and theirs (so far) is that they directly reference the ArenaNET project while I am attempting to reference the dll created by their ArenaNET project.

Comment: That error means that the .DLL itself is invalid.  The name of the reference is a red herring.  Make sure your project has the same "bitness" settings as the sample project.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft -- I paid much closer attention to the "bitness" of what I was building and was eventually able to solve my issue. I've tried to summarize my findings in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to solve my problem. David Browne's comment about checking the "bitness" lead me on the right path. I'll try to summarize what I learned.

**Does the name of the reference in a C# Framework Project matter?**

I have no idea if it matters, but I don't think it does. The name likely isn't the true issue; for me, I had to carefully ensure I had the right "bitness" for the dlls I was building.

**"bitness"???**

In case you're confused on this, the "bitness" refers to the platform. I.e. I've got a windows 64 bit machine, so I needed to be building my Visual Studio dlls for the x86 platform. Building the VS dlls for Win32 or x64 did not solve my problem.

*Important Note:* If you are building the dlls so you can put them somewhere else, be sure you are grabbing the dlls from the correct folder!!

**Can the name of the reference be changed, within Visual Studio? (2019 or earlier)**

I have no idea. If the name truly doesn't matter, then I imagine the reference name cannot be changed. Again, the name of the reference likely isn't the real issue.